# StoreRepository get($code) which does not exists

Tags: magento2, module, multistore, stores, repository

Till today all the code was okay, but after code review, I got that we use the method

`load()` on the store itself so I replaced it with

```
storeRepository->get($code)
```

Code what I'm talking about first fetched by `load()` then created the new entity by factory if it wasn't found. Right now after replacement, a problem occurred - method `get()` in storeRepository injects itself StoreFactory to create new store if it's not found, the problem is it fetches it from config,

but is it standard `core_config_data` Config ? If so, what parameters I should write to that config and what arguments in method `save()` of configuration should be used?

Comment: Can you update your full code?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Actually I'm testing some other approach if so I will provide text explanation. Can't post code since my Company Privacy Policy forbidden me to do so.

Comment: So as I came to apporach where it's usable the best way is to replace `$model->load()` with `$resourceModel->load()` and if it's not returning id create it with **factory** and save with `$resourceModel->save($factory)` or just get `$storeRepository->get($code)` with **Try catch block** and validate exception the method returns to create new entity with factory and save as above.

Comment: Should I provide it as answer and mark it as solved? Couldn't update.